# datetime columns losts time information after convertion to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider a panda dataframe df created with pd.read_csv() function.

df has 2 columns with type below:

```
df.dtypes:
DAT_RUN      object
DAT_FORECAST object
```

Some values:

```
DAT_RUN     DAT_FORECAST
0   2020-08-11 00:00:00.000     2020-08-11 00:00:00.000
1   2020-08-11 00:00:00.000     2020-08-11 01:00:00.000
2   2020-08-11 00:00:00.000     2020-08-11 02:00:00.000
3   2020-08-11 00:00:00.000     2020-08-11 03:00:00.000
4   2020-08-11 00:00:00.000     2020-08-11 04:00:00.000
...     ...     ...
```

As you can see, columns values are in date format.

1. I want to convert theses columns to datetime (NOT IN PLACE):

   pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_RUN'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

[image]

I lost time information in value.

whereas

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_FORECAST'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

[image]

keeps time information in value.

Why?

2. And also, I want to search rows with restrictions:

For example in csv file I have:

[image]

```
df.loc[df['DAT_RUN'] == "2020-08-10 03:00:00.000", "DAT_RUN"]
```

returns 0 rows:

```
Series([], Name: DAT_RUN, dtype: object)
```

Whereas

```
df.loc[df['DAT_FORECAST'] == "2021-06-11 06:00:00.000", "DAT_FORECAST"]
```

returns rows:

[image]

What are  the differences?

Answer (score 1):

If there is time with `00:00:00.000` pandas only not display it.

```
df['DAT_RUN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_RUN'])
df['DAT_FORECAST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_FORECAST'])
```

Check it:

```
print (df['DAT_RUN'].head().tolist())
```

For second issue seems are compared `object` columns instead `datetime`s, maybe not assigned back columns.

Comment: Thanks, you right for first issue.  I 'll try to convert to datetime before restrict rows.

Comment: Sorry but as you can see in csv file, I have some value for DAT_RUN with time different from 00:00:00. After convert it to datetime , panda continue to consider value as 00:00:00.000. I don't undestand.